# DataTable object initializer with Primary Key

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm having difficulty initializing a `DataTable` specifying the `Columns` and `PrimaryKey` with an object initializer:

```
private DataTable _products = new DataTable
    {
        Columns = { { "Product", typeof(string) }, { "Lot", typeof(string) }, { "Qty", typeof(int) } },
        PrimaryKey = Columns[0]  //Columns doens't exist in the current context
    };
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax if you want to use an object in it which is also initialized in it. But that wouldn't make much sense either.

Instead use the constructor since that is the appropriate place:

```
private DataTable _products;

public void ClassName()
{
    _products = new DataTable
    {
        Columns = { { "Product", typeof(string) }, { "Lot", typeof(string) }, { "Qty", typeof(int) } }
    };
    _products.PrimaryKey = new[] { _products.Columns[0] };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have written like this,

```
DataTable _products = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = { { "Product", typeof(string) }, { "Lot", typeof(string) }, { "Qty", typeof(int) } },
            //PrimaryKey = Columns[0]  //Columns doens't exist in the current context because, datatable is still initializing.
        };
        _products.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] {_products.Columns[0]}; //Columns exists here.
```

Comment: It's a field not a local variable